# Manipulate & use the results of UPDATE .... RETURNING

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

Here is a simple PostgreSQL update returning some data:

```
UPDATE table set num = num + 1
WHERE condition = true
RETURNING table.id, table.num
```

Is there a way to further use the returned results, as if they came from a select statement?  Something like this:

```
INSERT into stats
(id, completed)
SELECT c.id, TRUE
FROM
(
    UPDATE table set num = num + 1
    WHERE condition = true
    RETURNING table.id, table.num
) c
where c.num > 5
```

Or do I have to save the returned results into my application, then create a new query out of the returned results?

Comment: PostgreSQL version! It's the deciding factor here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of version 9.1, you can use an `UPDATE ... RETURNING` in a ["Common Table Expression" ("CTE")](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html), which for most purposes can be thought of as a named sub-query.

So for your purposes, you could use something like this:

```
WITH update_result AS
(
    UPDATE table set num = num + 1
    WHERE condition = true
    RETURNING table.id, table.num
)
INSERT into stats
(id, completed)
SELECT c.id, TRUE
FROM update_result as c
WHERE c.num > 5
```

If you're using a version of Postgres below 9.1, then I think you will have to grab the result into a variable in some procedural code - either your application, or a database function (probably written in [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql.html)).

Answer (score 0):

That syntax won't work (unfortunately! that would be convenient).

Either you update and then create another query, or you do everything in a `stored procedure` where you can safely store and handle query resuts, so that you just have one single database call from your application.